# How to use 'to_dm' function in model designer?

Tags: qgis-3, field-calculator, query-builder

When using the field calculator in an attribute table, it is easy to plug in the various fields you might need from the side bar option 'Fields and Variables'. However, in Model Designer this feature does not work (at least for me). I am trying to use the field calculator in model designer to convert some coordinates to decimal minutes using the equation: ("x", 'X', 6). However, it doesn't recognize the "x" as a field.

Here you can see the field calculator in the attribute table seems to work just fine.
[image]

Versus in the model designer where it doesn't recognize anything.

[image]

Any insight is appreciated.

This is the error I get with the Field Type changed to Text (string).

[image]

Problem was I didn't have the field name set as the resulting field but as a field that already existed.

[image]

Comment: Field type should be string and that it does not recognize a feature in preview is because no feature is loaded in the model at this point. Run it and it should work.

Comment: So it recognizes what I want but can't store the value? I put a new image in the original post showing the error I get after the Field Type is changed to Text (string). It still thinks it's double?

Comment: I solved the problem. I needed the Field Name in Field Calculator to be the resulting field. My mistake was that I was setting the Field Name to a column that already existed and was set as type double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this instance, the answer was to have the Field Name be the resulting Field, not an existing Field. I see now there is an option 'Create New Field' that I missed.